# How to render a form (Rails Simple_form) inside of a partial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

Here is the relevant code:

--- app/controllers/movies_controller.rb

```
    def show
        movie = convert_movie_data([Movie.find(params[:id])])
        @movie = movie[0]
        @movie_rating = movie[1]
        @comments = Comment.all

        if user_signed_in?
            @new_comment = new_movie_comment
        end
    end
```

at the console, @comments returns

```
     #<Comment id: nil, title: nil, comment: nil, user_id: 21, movie_id: 10, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

--- app/views/movies/show.html.haml

```
 = render partial: 'shared/new', locales: { new_comment_form: @new_comment }
```

The partial at "= partial" renders when user is not logged in.

Here is where the problem lies (I suspect):

--- app/views/shared/_new.html.erb

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
     <%= simple_form for new_comment_form:, method: :post, url: new_comment_path do |f| %>
        <%= f.input :title %>
        <%= f.input :comment %>
        <%= f.button :submit %>
    <% end %>
    You are signed in
<% else %>
    Please sign in to comment
<% end %>
```

I suspect the problem lies with the way I constructed the simple_form for tag.

At the controller, I injected values that where needed to construct the comment (current_user.id, movie_id) and at the show view, I attempted to transfer the instance variable through locales (new_comment_form:) but then I'm sure that I made a mistake with the construction of the simple form.

I was made aware of the fact that I did not supply the error message. Thanks for pointing that out @z3r0ss

```
SyntaxError at /movies/21

syntax error, unexpected ','
...ple_form_for new_comment_form:, method: :post, url: new_comm...
...                              ^
/app/views/shared/_new.html.erb:12: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input
          ensure
          ^~~~~
```

I hope that this helps, and thanks again for any input.

Answer (score 2):

First I would make sure that I'm sending a new instance of `Comment` from `MoviesController`

```
def show
  @comment = Comment.new
end
```

A couple of notes on this

1 - Remember you pass the `@movie` instance with a before_action (that would be useful if you are using the instance in other controller methods)

2 - You can access to all the comments that belong to the movie from the view with a `@movie.comments` (I'm assuming there is an association there!)

Regarding the form, you can try this:

```
<%= simple_form_for [@movie, @comment] do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :title%>
  <%= f.input :comment%>
  <%= f.submit 'Post comment'%>
<% end %>
```

And finally, at the `CommentsController`, remember to redirect to wherever you want. For example, the show of the same `@movie`

```
[...]
if @comment.save
  redirect_to @movie
else
  render 'movies/show'
end
```

Comment: Really appeciate the help on this @Fesivajacquier

Answer (score 0):

May be you can be clearer in terms of what errors you have. From the look of it, it looks like it's a syntax error. It should be `simple_form_for new_comment_form`  and not `simple_form for new_comment_form:`.

Comment: I noticed that... I fixed the error. Still no change in error message (which I posted above). Thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: @wacevedo you still have the syntax error which is the extra `:` after `new_comment_form`

Comment: Thanks z3r0ss for your advice, though I went a different route entirely. after playing with it for a while, it occurred to me that:
1. I could simply pass in the Instance variables into the partial... I didn't have to reference them with a symbols.
:locals => [@movie, @comment]
2nd: the order matters... it is a comment based on a movie [@movie, @comment]
so they have to be referenced the same way in the form definitions.  I took the afternoon off, rested my brain and came to this conclusion just now, 20 minutes after looking at the problem again.